# Mysql utf8 error on load data local infile

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to duplicate a mysql instance on Windows Server 2012.  Running into an issue importing a text file.

This works without issue on a local server on a Windows 8 Machine:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/somefile.txt' INTO TABLE invoicedata.invoicedata
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@col1, @col2)
set date = @col1, order_number = @col2;
```

When I run the same exact command on the server 2012 machine (same text file), I get:

```
Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8 character string
```

I am not sure why this would work on one and not the other.

Comment: Are you sure the text file is UTF-8 and not UTF-16 or Windows-1252?

Comment: How does `order_number` get populated correctly if you don't define `@col2` in `(@col1, col2)`?

Comment: I updated @col2, it was just a typo.

The issue I'm running into is that it is working fine on one machine (Windows 8), but not when I run it on Windows Server 2012.  The text file is UTF-8.